# OnMessageAsync() not always triggering

Tags: message-queue, azure-service-fabric, azureservicebus

Below is the exact code for my Azure Service Fabric Service Bus queue listener.
The problem I am having is that the  _client.OnMessageAsync "takes a rest" when not used for a few minutes.  It eventually wakes up and processes the queued messages, maybe within 5 minutes.  messages are never dropped or deadletter'd, but this is unacceptable behavior.  I tried tweaking message options, but nada..

Any ideas?

```
 internal sealed class Core : StatelessService
    {
        readonly QueueClient _client;
        readonly OnMessageOptions _msgOptions;

        public Core(StatelessServiceContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
            var connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(Resources.ServiceBusConnectionString);
            var inQueue = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(Resources.InQueue);
            var factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
            _client = factory.CreateQueueClient(inQueue, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
            _msgOptions = new OnMessageOptions
            {
                AutoComplete = false,
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 5

            };
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return new ServiceInstanceListener[0];
        }
        protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            _client.OnMessageAsync(
              async message =>
              {
                  OnReceived(message);
                  await message.CompleteAsync();
              }, _msgOptions),
              cancellationToken);
        }
        private void OnReceived(BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage)
        {
            var message = brokeredMessage.GetBody<Message>();
            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(Context, "Working-{0}", message.Transaction.Id);
            var preocessor = new Processor();
            preocessor.Process(message);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Is this a stateless or statfull service? What's the scale out? Do you see messages on the queue while service is "idle" ?

Comment: As shown above, its stateless.  There is no scaleout.  Its a single node running on a pc dev box..
I see messages on the queue.

Comment: Weird. Same behavior on a different namespace if you try?

Comment: I think its a problem with the message client..  I see triggers in the SF eventlog when new messages come in, but the client doesn't respond..

Comment: I assume you're on the latest version of ASB. Try that message pump outside of SF dev cluster.

Comment: latest and greatest, no issue outside the SF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135137/discussion-between-sean-feldman-and-lasttribunal).